# Strange NoClassDefFoundError when creating Type using TypeToken for Map

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to get java.lang.reflect.Type object for

```
Map<Integer, List<Object>>
```

When I do that I get strange exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.app.directions.DirectionsTask$1
    at com.app.directions.DirectionsTask.start(DirectionsTask.java:53)
    at com.app.directions.DirectionsDialog.onActivityCreated(DirectionsDialog.java:80)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1983)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1092)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Class DirectionsTask line 53 is where I call:

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, List<Object>>>(){}.getType();
```

In my other class I use it to get Type for List and it's working without any problems:

```
Type resultType = new TypeToken<List<Vehicle>>() { }.getType();
```

What's wrong with my code?

Below my DirectionsTask class:

```
public class DirectionsTask implements Callback<Direction[]> {

public void start() {
    Type mapType = new TypeToken<List<Object>>(){}.getType();
}

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Direction[]> call, Response<Direction[]> response) {
    Log.d("DirectionsTask", "onResponse: code=" + response.code() + "  message=" + response.message()
        + "  body=" + (response.body() != null ? Arrays.toString(response.body()) : "null"));
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<Direction[]> call, Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that inner class is also involved here. $1 in exception trace. If you are trying to access inner class or any of its field using reflection you need to use $ sign , just like following.

```
Class c = Class.forName("MainClassName$InnerClassName")
```

NoClassDefFoundError is thrown when Class Loader is unable to find definition of class at runtime.

Comment: But how is that possible?

Comment: Classpath doesn't have this class.

Comment: when I use other method from DirectionsTask (not the one which calls Type resultType = .....) then there's no exception

Comment: Okay I got your point. Does DirectionsTask  has a inner class?

Comment: actually DirectionsTask is really simple class, it doesn't have any inner classes. I've just updated my post with DirectionsTask class code

Comment: Perform clean build. Clean all temp folders and check your runtime libraries . Rerun app.

Comment: I did that but it didn't help. But I removed Android Studio files (.iml etc.) and opened again in Android Studio and now it works! Thanks for help.